# How to user PackageInstaller.SessionParams setGrantedRuntimePermissions method?

Tags: android, system, root, runtime-permissions

I'm building a system app (but not a signature app) to run as root in "kiosk mode". This app should install/uninstall third party apk's on runtime, according to the demand.

I need to install the third party app and immediately grant runtime permissions that the apk needs. After some research, I found the method (android.content.pm.PackageInstaller):

```
/**
     * Sets which runtime permissions to be granted to the package at installation.
     *
     * @param permissions The permissions to grant or null to grant all runtime
     *     permissions.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @SystemApi
    @RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS)
    public void setGrantedRuntimePermissions(String[] permissions) {
        installFlags |= PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS;
        this.grantedRuntimePermissions = permissions;
    }
```

As the annotation says, it can only be called if I declare INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS on my app manifest. So, in spite I could not find this permission in (android.Manifest), I added it to manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.xxx"
    >
[...]    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"/>
[...]
```

When I call the method on my code "params.setGrantedRuntimePermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION });" I immediately receive an error from Android Studio saying that cannot resolve the method. It is easily explained because there's a @hide instruction there, so I tried to workaround, and call the method by Reflection:

```
String[] permissions = new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION };
Method m = params.getClass().getMethod("setGrantedRuntimePermissions", new Class[] { String[].class } );
m.invoke(params, (Object)permissions);
```

But, in spite I have added the permission on Manifest, I still receive the security exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag
```

Extra info:

. The app is installed under /system/priv-app
. Compilation details:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
    }
```

. I was using this lib (eu.chainfire.libsuperuser.Shell) to grant the permission and it works but I wonder If I can have it done without using shell:

```
Shell.SU.run("pm grant com.thirdparty.package android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I was also trying to do the exact same thing and am currently struck. It seems even though the app is placed in /system/priv-app directory, android system doesn't grant this signature permissions automatically if declared in the manifest.I am seeing the following logcat prints on device boot.
" W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS to package com.xx.xx.xx (protectionLevel=770 flags=0x3848be47)"                                                 Were you able to workaround this?

Comment: At the time I solved the problem like i've mentioned and then I didn't get deeper on the subject. Sorry. Post here if you find a solution meanwhile for future purposes.